# Notify running Windows app when line is inserted in sql table

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, triggers, notifications

I need to have a Windows application (that I am writing) somehow get information that a new record has been added to a certain SQL table.  The SQL Server is MS SQL Server 2008, and the Windows app is a .NET 4 app.  The SQL Server and the running app are on different computers, but they are constants in this equation. What is the best way to get that notification to the running app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create a CLR trigger, which opens a `TcpClient` connection, from parameters stored in a config table. The app then creates a `TcpListener` object and waits for the CLR trigger to send data.  Seems to be working well.